# tracing all UI interaction for a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, trace

I'm trying to collect usage data for a WPF application, specifically which features are used how often and by what means (mouse interaction, accelerator keys, shortcuts, ...). However, sometimes I'm interested in additional information like cursor position (e.g. how long does the user hover before deciding to (not) click) or scrolling behavior, too.

Consequently, I want to log all UI interaction, so that I can filter out unneeded information later on. Of course, performance must not be impacted noticeably. Another requirement, which makes things complicated, is that **I don't want to add tracing code throughout the entire application**.

My first idea was to use the "built-in" WPF Tracing by enabling the `PresentationTraceSources` and adding a custom listener (derived from `TraceListener` and implemented with the Producer-Consumer pattern).

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    // Activate WPF Tracing
    PresentationTraceSources.Refresh();                             
    WPFListener = new AsyncPrototypeListener("WPFTrace.log");
    var filter = new PrototypeTraceFilter();
    WPFListener.Filter = filter;
    WPFListener.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.Timestamp;
    // Detach default listener (console) for performance reasons
    PresentationTraceSources.RoutedEventSource.Listeners.Clear();   
    PresentationTraceSources.RoutedEventSource.Listeners.Add(WPFListener);
    PresentationTraceSources.RoutedEventSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.All;
}
```

This does capture all relevant interaction without a noticeable performance impact in my test application, but I get the data as a shitload of redundant strings (logged to a file unfiltered it amounts to ~10 MB for each second the application runs). But the real problem is something else:

Sadly, the RoutedEventSource is provided with just the string representation of the captured events, rendering me unable to retrieve the useful information (e.g. name of the source control) thus leaving me with just type names.

Long story short, I don't see a way to get the wanted information from the WPF tracing. In result, I need to find another way to trace UI usage without manually implementing it everywhere.

My next idea was to create a Window base class, that has EventHandlers for relevant actions (e.g. MouseDown, KeyDown, ...). This, however, causes several problems:

- I have to change all Windows to use this class. This is especially problematic for third party components that may open own dialogs.
- Some events don't find their way down to the bottom of the VisualTree (I noticed this for MouseScroll, my handler won't trace any scrolling inside a child component with a scrollbar, only outside where scrolling has no effect).
- Tracing everything that works with commands (which is a lot because of MVVM) won't be easy, if possible at all (especially for keyboard interaction).

Now I'm stuck. Another idea I had was to do some black magic with reflection (like decorating all commands and event handlers), but I'm not sure how to do this or if it is even possible. Is there anything I fail to see? Does anyone know how to best approach this problem?

EDIT: An own implementation of `ICommand`, like suggested by Sinatr, won't work if I want to capture the internal workings of third party components, too (which I have to since the application relies heavily on DevExpress).

EDIT2: I'm currently looking into PostSharp for tracing. I'd say it looks promising.

EDIT3: With some more or less sophisticated filtering, PostSharp will be able to do everything I need in my assembly - for third party it's still problematic. There is [a possibility to inject PostSharp in DLLs](https://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/applying-aspects-to-3rd-party-assemblies-using-postsharp/), but I can't get it to work. Also, Postsharp isn't really cheap...

EDIT4: Looking into Afterthought and SheepAspect as possible PostSharp alternatives...

Comment: Sounds broad. To *record* mouse/keyboard events you can use *hooks*. To record command executions (wpf mvvm) you can use a specific implementation of `ICommand`. Etc.

Comment: @Sinatr I read about that, and also found that `RawInput` is [often preferred over hooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx), but for both the problem is that I only get the input without the needed context - the resulting action taken in the application

Comment: Log both. Record input (mouse movements) and UI actions (commands) separately using your preferred logger. Then just combine them using date/time stamps to get statistic you mentioned (how long user wasn't clicking after certain page appears, etc.).

Comment: @Sinatr ok, but this still leaves the problem how to log the commands - any logger I know needs to be manually notified for each command, and that's exactly what I want to avoid

Comment: @Sinatr sorry saw your remark regarding `ICommand` too late - but still, this won't work for third party components and `ApplicationCommands`

Comment: what about using preview_events on the containing window?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was thinking... maybe it will help

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication9"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        PreviewMouseDown="Window_PreviewMouseDown"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="sampleButton" Click="Button_Click" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication9
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("button is after preview!");
        }

        private void Window_PreviewMouseDown(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("preview down");

            // could loop thorugh all the UI elements and check IsMouseOver ?  <---- might be a better method. 
            if(button1.IsMouseOver)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("button about to be clicked");
            }

            e.Handled = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but unfortunately this won't help me in capturing all the needed events - your approach is basically one of polling, but I want to be notified or intercept/decorate the normal handlers